# Why am I getting double logs in dev and no logs in production from custom rails classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I'm trying to sort out an odd bug where I get double log output in my local dev environment, but no logs in production. I'm using `rails 4.2.1`, `ruby 2.2.2`, `puma 2.14.0`, and a `heroku free account`.

I have a custom class, `component_decorator.rb` which looks like this:

```
module ComponentsDecorator
  include Enumerable

  def self.decorate()
    Rails.logger.debug  " "
    Rails.logger.debug  "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    Rails.logger.debug  "ComponentsDecorator:"
    Rails::logger.info  "Test of 'Rails::logger.info' logging"
    Rails.logger.info   "Test of 'Rails.logger.info' logging"
    Rails::logger.debug "Test of 'Rails::logger.debug' logging"
    Rails.logger.debug  "Test of 'Rails.logger.debug' logging"
    puts                "Test of 'puts' logging"
    Rails.logger.debug  "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
    Rails.logger.debug  " "
  end
end
```

In my local dev environment when I run `ComponentDecorator.decorate({})` I get:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ComponentsDecorator:
ComponentsDecorator:
Rails.logger.inspect: #<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x007ff4553fc1d0 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007ff4553fc0b8 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007ff454e4ff70 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007ff4553fc018 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:/dev/null>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007ff4553fdaa8 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007ff454e4ff98>>>>
Rails.logger.inspect: #<RailsStdoutLogging::StdoutLogger:0x007ff4553fc1d0 @progname=nil, @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007ff4553fc0b8 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007ff454e4ff70 @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007ff4553fc018 @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:/dev/null>, @mutex=#<Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007ff4553fdaa8 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Mutex:0x007ff454e4ff98>>>>
Test of 'Rails::logger.info' logging
Test of 'Rails::logger.info' logging
Test of 'Rails.logger.info' logging
Test of 'Rails.logger.info' logging
Test of 'Rails::logger.debug' logging
Test of 'Rails::logger.debug' logging
Test of 'Rails.logger.debug' logging
Test of 'Rails.logger.debug' logging
Test of 'puts' logging
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However in Production on Heroku, I don't see any logs from this class (although I do see logs from normal rails classes like `controllers`, `models`, etc.)

Another odd thing I noticed was that if I remove the `gem 'rails_12factor'` I get regular, single output in my local env.

One theory is that perhaps the custom class is re-declairing a new logger, unfortunately I'm not really sure how to verify that. Any insight would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

**production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
  config.assets.compress
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

**config.ru**

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application

# For Heroku live logs
$stdout.sync = true
```

Comment: Can you show a config setting from `config/environments/production.rb`, exactly `config.log_level` ?

Comment: @Зелёный - added to question; `log_level` is set to `:debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was actually that I had two classes with the same name; Apparently `ruby` doesn't doesn't throw an error in that event and because `config.eager_load` is set to `false` in dev, it always worked. The app always ended up loading the class without logging in production first which is why I never saw any messages.

Answer (score 1):

**rails_12factor** introduces the gem **rails_stdout_logging,** which adds its own logging to the Logger class, here:

https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/blob/master/lib/rails_stdout_logging/rails.rb

Comment: Right, but how / why do regular rails classes log properly, but custom classes do not?

Comment: have you tried removing "config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)" from your config file? rails_stdout_logging should set the logger for you